# How to link JS route var and Symfony 2 URLs

Tags: javascript, php, symfony

I would like to know what is the most flexible solution to link SF2 routes & a JS var which is containing the routes.
For static routes, I don't have any problems, but when I want to connect URL with parameters, i did not find any solution (not hard-coded).

How can I do if I edit the routing.yml file, Dynamics URL on change

I'm using `var url = "domain.com/path/to/url/with/" + token + "/and/" + name` for generating but it is not flexible.

I know that twig generated urls are server side etc...

Any solutions ?

Ex :

**JS**

```
var route = {
    home : "{{ path("home") }}",
    custom_route : "{{ path("my_custom_route") }}"
}
```

**Routing.yml**

```
my_custom_route:
    pattern:  /path/to/url/with/{token}/and/{name}
    defaults: { _controller: "SupboxCloudBundle:Public:file" }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could try [FOSJSRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle).

Answer (score 0):

Well, this sort of depends on the result you are trying to achieve. Are you doing this in some sort of JS app?

If it were me, I would render the routes, or route parameters in the DOM. I wouldn't mess with rendering anything in the JS and I would make the JS code abstract.

For instance:

```
<div data-custom="{{ path("my_custom_route") }}"></div>
<div data-home="{{ path('home') }}"
```

or

```
<a href="{{ path("my_custom_route") }}" data-route="home">whatever</a>
```

then you can grab your routes in JS when needed (from the first example):

```
var route = {
    home: $('div[data-home]').data('home'),
    custom_route: $('div[data-custom]').data('custom')
}
```

This is a little messy as I'm just trying to show you a concept. However your actual implementation would depend on the actual result you are trying to achieve.

If you comment a more specific intent below I will provide a better solution for you.